# on session start event

Tags: asp.net, session

I'm building a web application: some pages will be accessible by non logged-in users (demo and sign-up pages) and others will only be accessible by logged-in users (actual application). In the global.asax file, I'm currently handling the session start event by loading some variable from a query that's based on the UserID. What will happen when a non-logged in user looks at a page? I guess my question is really about how to handle the session start event when it's a logged-in user, when it's not and when a user logs in. I want a certain number of queries to run only once per session, after the user logged in.

Thanks.

Comment: Umm...What does session start event have to do with user logging in or not? Once you verify the user (logged user), you will serve respective pages based on the verification method you employ....whether it be cookied or cookieless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't confuse "login session" with "session state". Session state has nothing to do with whether the user is logged in.

If you want some queries run when the user logs in, you should run them *when the user logs in*, not in Session_Start.

Comment: got it, thanks. BTW, where is the event "user logged in" handled?

Comment: @frenchie: that would depend on how the suer logs in. If you have control of the login page, then you have control of this event.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to implement Forms-Based Authentication, instead of to handle authentication via session. An example can be obtained from here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240